# Can't display image which I load from user

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use the blueimp-file-upload node. I imported it and used the sample code from the website. I can load my image but can't display it on the screen. I have not a result div I know, but on the website there I can't find a result code. I just want to display my image which I load in a div so I can see it on the website.

In My `.html` file I have just the reference to the node and my `.js` file

```
<script src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-load-image/2.24.0/load-image-exif-map.js"></script>
<script scr="./load.js"></script>
```

And my .js file looks like this

```
document.getElementById("file-input").onchange = function(e) {
    loadImage(
        e.target.files[0],
        function(img) {
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        },
        { maxWidth: 600 } // Options
    );
};
```

Comment: with the code i posted i have a button where i can upload a file from my computer but it isnt show. As far i see the js function document.getElementById("file-input").onchange = function(e) has not  a return value. I dont understand how i can display ma loaded image

Comment: please provide [mcve], including the code of `loadImage`. Also, please fix the `scr` bit and describe the behavior you get with that fixed

Answer (score 1):

You have `scr` instead of `src` !

```
<script src="./load.js"></script>
```

Comment: I wrote src or not ?

Comment: you have written scr

Comment: i dont understand what you mean ?

Comment: Uh xD .. I have overlooked that .. But it's still not working, i can load the image but don't see it.

Comment: can you share the loadImage function. ? better yet create a fiddle or stackblitz so that it is easier to debug ?